# Get ID by key in localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

In JS localStorage I can use

```
localStorage.getItem(key);
```

to get the value of the entry corresponding to the key in the `key` variable.

How can I get the entry's ID (instead of value) using the key?

Edit: sorry I must have confused people. What I mean by "key" is the numerical key - which is 0, 1, 2, 3 etc depending on how many items have been saved. Then I want to find out the ID it was stored as, eg foo in the below example, from the numerical key.

`localStorage.setItem('foo', 'bar');`

Comment: Why do you want to do that? From what I can see in [the spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#dom-storage-key), adding and removing keys may change the order of existing keys, so you can't really count on the numeric index actually meaning anything useful...

Comment: I want to populate a `<select>` menu with DB entries. The `<select>` menu will be wiped and repopulated each time the program changes something in the DB.

Comment: Ah, OK. So a `for` loop with `localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i))` (where `i` is obviously the loop counter from `0` to `localStorage.length`) should do it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LocalStorage is implemented as a key-value pair ( see for instance: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideHtml5Storage ) - so you don't have an id like an unique auto-incremented id in a database table.

However, you can access the elements using an index - to get the index of a key in localStorage, the only way I can find is to loop through each key until you find the one you are searching for, like this:

```
var findIndexOfKey = function(searchKey) {
    for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){
        var key = localStorage.key(i);
        if(key === searchKey)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

And then, to retrieve the key using the index, you can do:

```
localStorage.key(myIndex);
```

And to retrieve the value, you can do this:

```
localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(myIndex));
```

... or this ( which would be equivalent to `localStorage.getItem("myKey")`):

```
localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(findIndexOfKey("myKey")));
```

Comment: Thanks. Something similar to that is what I ended up using.

Comment: I like your implementation of `findIndexOfKey()`, but regarding the last line of your answer: isn't that the same as `localStorage.getItem("myKey")`?

Comment: @nnnnnn you're absolutely right - that might have been a bit too simple example - I have edited my samples and included some different use-cases ( and added a missing `)` to the samples as well ) - thanks for your comments :)

Answer (score 0):

when setting the item you should give it's ID as a value and than when you call getItem(key) it should give it's ID as a return ex:

```
localStorage.setItem('foo', 'bar');
localStorage.getItem('foo');  // it should return the bar
```

take a look for this examples it may help : http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/localstorage-pattern

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't help. In your example, `foo` is the ID and `bar` is the value. The key would be 0, 1, 2, 3 etc, depending on how many values have been saved. What I want is to return the ID (`foo`) when given the numerical key.

Comment: `localStorage.key(n)` should return the nth key, but I don't think there's a method to go the other way. You could use `.key()` together with the `.length` property to loop through each item yourself. Note also that adding or removing a key could change the order of existing keys. (http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#dom-storage-key)

Comment: @nnnnnn Thanks. Just realized that before seeing your comment and so I've answered the question. I got the names of stuff confused...

Comment: he's right their is no straight way to get the specific ID your looking for you have to find a walk around to solve your problem i searched on google and i couldn't find a straight way to do that i'm sorry

Answer (score 0):

The answer:

```
localStorage.key(key);
```

Sorry, I realise I've got confused between what's actually called the key, which I called the ID, and it's numerical ID which I called the key...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible. Can't you just make `localStorage.setItem(yourkey,value)`? I mean

```
localStorage.setItem(0,value)  
localStorage.setItem(1,value)
```

This may be useful in loops for example.